# Database: Best way to model these requirements?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I've got the following requirements for a timesheet in a web application:

- Users can create entries
- Entries can only be created and modified in the current month and in the last month if it isn't "closed".
- A month gets closed automatically on the tenth day on the currenth month or earlier if a user manually choses to do so.

Currently, I've got the tables User and Entry with the following attributes:

User:

- id
- name

Entry:

- id
- userid
- date
- starttime
- endtime
- notes

The question is: What's the best way to model my requirements in the database?

My idea is to add a boolean field "lastMonthIsClosed" to the table User and schedule a monthly job which sets the field to true for all users on the tenth day of each month and to false for all users on the first day of each month. Alternatively, it could also be a date field "lastClosedMonth"...

I'm wondering whether there is a more elegant approach to model these requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Closed" isn't an attribute of a user or of a month. It's an attribute of an entry.

```
create table entry (
  id integer primary key,
  userid integer not null,
  start_time timestamp not null,
  end_time timestamp not null default current_timestamp 
    CHECK(start_time < end_time),
  notes varchar(255),
  closed boolean not null default FALSE
);
```

Consider additional constraints on the duration.

- Must be more than 1 minute.
- Must be at least 6 minutes. (One tenth of an hour.)
- Must be less than 9 hours.
- Must be less than 24 hours.

You can create a view to expose only the open entries to the users.

Add a [row-level BEFORE UPDATE trigger](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html) to that table to prevent changes to closed entries. The trigger will prevent both users and database administrators from changing a closed entry. A row-level BEFORE INSERT trigger can prevent users and admins from inserting a row based on its timestamps.

Decide now what to do with timeslips that straddle the change from one month to the next.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What about the restriction on creating new entries? If "closed" is an attribute of an entry, then it's possible to prevent the editing of existing entries (by setting closed to true) but how to prevent the creation of new entries in the last month? Also, does it really make sense for "closed" to be an attribute of entry? It will be set on a monthly basis anyway... it's not possible to close just a few items in a month, it's all or nothing.

Comment: See above: "row-level BEFORE INSERT trigger". I think it does make sense to think of "closed" as an attribute of entry. "Close a month" really means "close a month's worth of entries". And someday you'll probably be told something like, "Heinrich is under investigation for embezzling and obstruction of justice. Close all his time entries between the fourth and the twelfth of this month."

Comment: You're right, it does make sense. However, I still do not completely understand your solution. Let's say I've got three entries: a, b, c
a and b are in the last month, c is in the current month, today is the fifth day of the month. Now the user decides to close the entries of the last month, so I mark entries a and b as "closed". How do I determine that no entries may be inserted with a date in the last month? What should the aforementioned trigger do or check for? Based on the timestamp it's okay to insert the entry because the day of the current month is <= 10 (see requirements above).

Comment: You'd need to store the fact that "User 'n' has closed time entries that end between '2011-07-01' and '2011-07-31', and the triggers would also need to refer to the table that fact is stored in.

Comment: Yeah, and that's about the same as my idea in the initial post, isn't it? Still, thanks for your help and time!

Comment: I think you need both. The facts about when a month is closed is different from the facts about when a timeslip is closed. Different facts, different predicates. Different predicates, different tables.